# Nested Structs without declaring type

Tags: go

I know that we can do something more or less that looks like this:

```golang
type Struct1 struct {
    someString string
    someInt    int
}

type Struct2 struct {
    someString string
    someStruct []Struct1
}

var s Struct2 = Struct2{"abc", []{Struct1{"def", 123}, Struct1{"ghi", 456}}}
```

But I would like to know if you can do something anonymous for data I won't need anywhere else than in a specific place. I would like to avoid writing redundant code, I am looking for something like this:

```golang
var s = struct {
        someString string, someStructs[] struct {
            x string, y int
        }
    } {
        "ok", []{
            {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure it works if you use the correct syntax, but rarely is it ever helpful to do so in your code: https://play.golang.org/p/IuctLmOxy4j. If you're declaring different types, it's not redundant, and makes the code easier to work with.

Comment: The slice of anonymous type requires you to repeat the type declaration but other than that you can do pretty much exactly what you described.

Comment: @JimB Thank you, I accepted Burak's answer because it answer to my question, but I still went with your suggestion for my coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but it is somewhat tedious if you have nested anonymous structs:

```
var s = struct {
        someString string, 
        someStructs[] struct {
            x string
            y int
        }
 } {
  someString: "ok",
  someStructs: []struct{ x string, y int } {
            {"1", 2}, {"3", 4}, {"5", 6}
        }
 }
```